# Firefox showing an error message while downloading .xlsx file

Tags: microsoft-excel, firefox

I have uploaded a file say 'filename.xlsx' file to the server. While downloading the file in firefox the file is downloaded as filename.xlsx.xls and i get the error mentioned below while trying to open it. I have no idea why firefox adds an xls extension to the .xlsx file while other browser downloads the file correctly as 'filename.xlsx

> The file format and extension of 'filename.xlsx.xls' don't match. The
>   file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't
>   open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Without the link to the file you're downloading, my guess is that the site hosting the file has Content-Type set to `application/vnd.ms-excel` while it should actually be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, thus Firefox is giving the file a proper extension based on the information provided by the server.

I've only observed this behavior on Windows. The Linux version of Firefox doesn't add extensions regardless of the MIME type.